# Javascript Remove field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to Add the ability to Remove a field on my form with Javascript but It isn't working. I have commented out my Remove field below. How can I fix it?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append("<div><select name='tournament_id_" + x + "'> <%=j(options_from_collection_for_select(Tournament.all.where(tour_id: 1), 'id', 'event'))%></select></div>")


        // <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'") //add input box
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you have many errors

[JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/DeveloperH/a2pLu96m/16/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
add_button.click(function (e) { //on add input button click

   if ($(".containers").length < 11 ) { //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        wrapper.append('<div id="container_' + x + '" class="containers"><select name="tournament_id_' + x + '"><option>1</option> </select><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove_field" data-id="' + x + '">Remove</a></div><br>') //add input box
    }
});

wrapper.on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
    id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $("#container_" + x).remove();
    x--;});});
```

Comment: when I added it to my code block the color in all my other javascript changed. Should I post what i have underneath this code block too?

Comment: I will do for you new code in jsfiddle within 5 min, I will share the code with you

Comment: It's because `"#container_'` has mixed quotation marks, try to change it to both `'` or both `"`.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement in Console

Comment: mmmm, did you copy it for jsfiddel? it works there. do you have something else you dont show it to me???

Comment: Thanks for you help! But in the answer you've provided and the JSFiddle you've added an <option> tag but in my application I am using an ERB tag to dynamically draw out options in my input box. I think this may be part of the problem I am having

Comment: I think ERB write option attribute in " and we use ' for attribute I will edit it now and try it again